# Form and database, plugin development

Tags: plugin-development, database, forms

I'm developing my first plugin. It creates directories and save the path, level (if it is a subdirectory of other created directory) and name in a custom table, created at the activation.

The plugin has an option page where users can manager the files in each directory or create more directories and upload more files. In this option page I had to create a form with action atribute as `<?php echo EASYDM_PLUGIN_URL; ?>generate-dir.php`.

The problem is when I try to use the constants like `WP_CONTENT_URL`, `ABSPATH` wordpress tells me they are undefined constants... just in this page of action atribute. Why?

I tried `add_action( 'admin_init', 'easydm_register_settings' );` with `register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'easydm_settings' );` and so on, but when I click in submit button the page redirects me to the **file.php** in action but as **wp-admin/file.php**. So, neither the first nor the second way are working for me. How can I do that?

Comment: i think you need to define ABSPATH and other constants within the plugin code like: `
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );`

Comment: kinda pointless to ask "why my code is not working" without showing it. No need to dump all your code, just relevant parts

Comment: If your code is overly long or spread across multiple files, you can use http://pastebin.com to create snippets that you can link to in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Post the form instead back to the same admin page you are coming from instead (basically using `form action=''`), then detect the form posting on that page (eg. `if (isset($_POST['createdir']))`, and *then* include the file that will actually process the request (eg. `include(EASYDM_PLUGIN_URL.'generate-dir.php');`)